# partial differentia equation and Laplace transformate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

let the following differential equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}= a^2 \dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}, 0<x<l, t>0\\
y(0,t)=f(t)\\
y(x,0)=0\\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x,0)=0
\end{cases}
$$

How we calculate the solution of this problem using Laplace transformate?
Thank's to the help.

Comment: There are videos solving this exact problem on youtube.

Comment: Can you give me the link? Please. Thank you so mutch